# How to transform a string in function and concatenate with an object?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, remoteobject

I have the following code in actionscript 3:

```
var async:AsyncToken;

async = bridge.retornamenu();
```

The bridge is a remote object, instantiated.
The retornamenu() is the function that I want the remote object open in amfphp.

However the retornamenu() is a dynamic function, which turns another function, but I can not run it at runtime,

example

```
var stringfunction:String = "retornamenu()" // this name is dynamic.

var async:AsyncToken;

async = bridge.stringfunction;
```

But this way does not work, not perform the function retornamenu();

someone could help me? 
I am a few days behind the solution, my project stopped,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getOperation()` and `send()` it.

```
var stringfunction:String = "retornamenu" // this name is dynamic.    
var async:AsyncToken;
async = bridge.getOperation(stringfunction).send();
```

If there are arguments to the function, you can pass it through `send(args)`

Comment: Hello, your solution worked perfectly, thank you, saved my night ...

I will study more about getOperation () and send ()


Thanks again

Comment: How could I pass arguments for function? explain to me more so this part?

Comment: `bridge.addNumbers(1,2,3)` => `bridge.getOperation("addNumbers").send(1,2,3)`